# R: How to split a string into values and map the resultant broken pieces as columns to the dataset?

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr, melt

[image]

As shown in the above pic, I've a column, genres, with a list of genres the corresponding movie belongs to. There are in total 19 unique genres. I'd like to know if I can manipulate this data into appending 19 columns to the data set each corresponding to each of the genres identifiers and label the corresponding cells as 0 or 1 indicating the movies affiliation to the each genre columns.

It should look something like below picture.

[image]

Comment: @akrun - whoops, grabbed the wrong one. Should be better now. SO recently just introduced the ability to edit duplicates by the way. Feel free to change it again if you find a better one.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this after splitting the 'genres' column

```
library(qdapTools)
d1 <- mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df1$genres),","))
row.names(d1) <- sub("\\s*\\(.*", "", df1$title)
```

---

Or another option is to create a matrix with column names as 'genres' and then do a comparison on the splitted string

```
m1 <- matrix(0, dimnames = list(sub("\\s*\\(.*", "", df1$title), 
      c("Adventure", "Animation", "Children",
   "Comedy", "Fantasy", "Romance", "Action", "Crime", "Thriller")), ncol=9, nrow = nrow(df1))
m1 + (t(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df1$genres), ","), function(x) colnames(m1) %in% x)))
#         Adventure Animation Children Comedy Fantasy Romance Action Crime Thriller
#Toy Story         1         1        1      1       1       0      0     0        0
#Jumanji           1         0        1      0       1       0      0     0        0
#Heat              0         0        0      0       0       0      1     1        1
```